# Compute minimum detectable effect in multiple logistic regression

Tags: logistic, effect-size

I would like to calculate what effect size a given sample size, in a multiple logistic regression, is sensitive to detect.
Do you have any advice? Is there a way in R?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to perform an effect-size sensitivity analysis in order to calculate the minimum effect size detectable given a certain power a sample size for a logistic regression model. Is there an R package?